# How exactly hyperledger fabric CA works

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am confused about how fabric-ca works. Its my first time working with CA. I have followed official fabric-ca documentation and have following question.

This is how i approach starting up a CA server and then enroll and register a client identity.

1- I start fabric ca server via docker, my docker

```
fabric-ca:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
  container_name: fabric-ca
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  environment:
    - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    - FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-client
    - FABRIC_CA_LOGLEVEL=debug
    - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=fabric-ca
  volumes:
    - "./fabric-ca-server:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server"
    - "./fabric-ca-client:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-client"
  command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b rootadmin:rootadminpw'
```

2- Now docker container starts successfully and i have following files/certs generated in my PWD.

```
▶ tree .
.
├── fabric-ca-client
├── fabric-ca-dokcer-compose.yaml
└── fabric-ca-server
    ├── ca-cert.pem
    ├── fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
    ├── fabric-ca-server.db
    └── msp
        └── keystore
            └── 45eed6744814fc8f2055ead83036b9bb15e5b9c5c5fd2b36db2419a7e585b8c3_sk

4 directories, 5 files
```

3. I have followed this tutorial about OpenSSL (https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/), according to which we need a self signed root certificate.
   *** I understand that certificates generated above are self signed root certificates.**

4- Now according to fabric-ca documentation we need to enroll a bootstrap identity

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://rootadmin:rootadminpw@localhost:7054
```

This command generates crypto files and config file in `fabric-ca-client` directory as follow

```
▶ tree .                                                                
.
├── fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
└── msp
    ├── cacerts
    │   └── localhost-7054.pem
    ├── intermediatecerts
    │   └── localhost-7054.pem
    ├── keystore
    │   └── b06fc324d2176a14db0fde95a951f846b57e533ea34bf94ab231345bdf3b13a5_sk
    └── signcerts
        └── cert.pem

5 directories, 5 files
```

So what is diffrence between these crypto and cryptos generated on server, especiall `.pem` files.

And also what is relation between server and client crypto files? Are these client cryptos are signed by server?

And also if i run above `fabric-ca-client` command multiple times, `.pem` files remain same but i get multiple files in `keystore` folder, which i understand are private keys.

Lastly, what exactly is diffrence between enroll and register command?

Comment: wow, so much help in here :(

Comment: xD I'm searching for an answer aswell..